# What bolded word represent here

Tags: single-word-requests

Half-orphaned at the age of twelve, Vincent decided to support his mother and the dog, Puppy, for the two **summed up** to everything that was left of him.

Comment: Please take the Tour again and consider the purpose of this site. You are on the wrong site. Try English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0):

I think "**summed up**" is being used here to mean "**Total**" or:

- "**everything**... that **was** left to him.**"
- **the only things... that had been** left to him.

These are just different ways to phrase the same thought.

That is:

*Vincent decided to support his mother and the dog because these were all he had left.  He had nothing else to think or care about.*

I assume the dog is called "Puppy" as some form of irony.

Irony: the expression of one's meaning by using language that normally signifies the opposite, typically for humorous or emphatic effect.

In english we would normally only refer to a new born or young dog [say] up to 1-year old, as a 'Puppy'(noun).  The text does not give the age of the dog, so 'Puppy' may be the 'pet-name' that Vince called the dog when it was young and did not bother to think of a proper name like 'Rover' or 'Fang'.  He continued to use this 'pet-name' even though the puppy had grown up and its animal type would normally be identified as 'dog'.

Comment: Good answer, but why should we believe you?  Please back up your answer with cited sources.

Comment: If you check any good thesaurus I think you will find 'TOTAL' listed.  From the alternative synonyms, I think this is the best meaning in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't good enough.  You need to *cite* sources *in your work*.  Refer to the "Provide Context" section in the Help Centre: "*Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*" [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)